# Detect button being tapped - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm working with objective-c and I want to detect when the user is tapping a button (not when he tapped it, but the actual moment when is being taped until he stops). 
Is there any method? I'm not finding it if there's any.
Thanks

Comment: use `touchDown` event of the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `touchDown` event you can make an action while your button is pressed

[image]

**Example**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func testing(_ sender: Any) {
        label.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    @IBAction func testingCancel(_ sender: Any) {
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
    }

    @IBAction func testingUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
    }


}
```

Comment: Easy but nice answer...!

Comment: Thanks @Krunal very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here ([UIControlEvents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents)) are all events of control/actions (with their brief description)

> - `UIControlEventTouchCancel`: A system event canceling the current touches for the control.
> - **UIControlEventTouchDown**: **A touch-down event in the control; when button is tapped/pressed.**
> - `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat`: A repeated touch-down event in the control; for this event the value of the UITouch tapCount method is
>     greater than one.
> - `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter`: An event where a finger is dragged into the bounds of the control.
> - `UIControlEventTouchDragExit`: An event where a finger is dragged from within a control to outside its bounds.
> - `UIControlEventTouchDragInside`: An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control.
> - `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`: An event where a finger is dragged just outside the bounds of the control.
> - `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`: A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.
> - `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`: A touch-up event in the control where the finger is outside the bounds of the control.

Use **Touch Down** to get button tapping event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

Button has following events to listen

[image]

You can use `Touch Down`